# JAVA (I've tried reversing two String using for loop

Tags: windows

(1) Can anyone tell me how do I declare array org[] and rev[] where I'm storing my two strings the original and reverse string?
(2) When I'm trying to store the characters of original String in org[] using charAt() they are throwing me an error.
    Can anyone help me out on reversing two strings without making use of reverse() instead making use of for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a = "12345";
char [] original= a.toCharArray();
char[] reverse = new char[a.length()];
int j =0;
for(int i=reverse.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    reverse[j] = original[i]; 
    j++;
}

System.out.println(new String(reverse));
```

Comment: Can we use new keyword inside System.out.println() ?

Comment: We can even print the reverse String using System.out.println(reverse) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick method you can use (must go inside your class):

```
public static void getCharacters(String input, char[] forward, char[] reverse)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
  {
    forward[i] = input.charAt(i);
    reverse[i] = input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i);
  }
}
```

This assumes that forward and reverse were already allocated, and were initialized to the length of the string input. Example usage from inside another method:

```
String input = "Hello, world!";
char[] forward = new char[input.length()];
char[] reverse = new char[input.length()];
getCharacters(input, forward, reverse);
// forward and reverse now contain the characters from input
```

Comment: Thank you Anish !

Comment: No problem :) if this helped, please consider upvoting or accepting this or the other answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry Anish since I'm new to the website so, how do I upvote and accept the answers ?

Comment: On the top left of each answer, there are up and down arrows above and below a number. These arrows are for up and down voting. Click an arrow to up or down vote. If you asked the question the answers are for, there will also be a checkmark. Click the checkmark to accept an answer so that all on StackOverflow see your issue has been resolved.  You can upvote any number of answers, but can only accept one per question. Both actions reward the person who gave the answer with some reputation points.

Comment: Why am I getting an error which states that mine method getCharacters(String, char[], char[]) are undefined for the type respective class ?? .. I can run this program importing ( import java.util.*; ) ?

Comment: oh, then your issue has not been resolved :/ can you post an updated snippet?

Comment: how are you calling getCharacters? what changes have you made to the rest of your code?

Comment: When I'm trying to call getCharacters(input, forward, reverse) from my main function which is inside the class Palindrome they are throwing me an error which states the method getCharacters(String, char[], char[]) is undefined for the class Palindrome ... Do I need to import any packages here Anish ?

Comment: You would have been defining getCharacters as a separate method outside your main method as described above. The example usage would go inside your main method, the rest would go elsewhere inside your class, but outside the main method.

Comment: No package is required though.